# set_xticklabels in an animated bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an animated bar chart in python where I would like to display the height of each bar on the x-axis at each frame. For that purpose, I use set_xticklabels to reset the xticks. It actually works nice, with one exception: if I run the animation and the number of bars is >8, then only half of the xtickslabels are displayed. So my question is: how can one set the step size of the xticks in an animation so I can see all of them no matter how many bars there are? Below is a minimal for means of demonstration (with some comments which are hopefully helpful). Please try yourself with different numbers of bars (stored in the variable l):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation


n=100 #number of frames
l=8  #number of bars

def test_func(k): #just some test function, has no further meaning
    A=[]
    for i in range (l):
        numerator=(i+1)*k
        denominator=(i+k+1)**2+1
        A.append(numerator/float(denominator))
    return A

barlist=[] # the list of bars that is reused in each frame
for i in range(l):
    barlist.append(0)


fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes(xlim=(-1,l),ylim=(0,0.5)) # the ticks are centered below each
                                      # bar; that's why the x-axis starts
                                      # at -1; otherwise you see only
                                      # half of the first bar.
barchart=ax.bar(range(l),barlist,align='center')


def animate(i):
    y=test_func(i)
    newxticks=[''] # since the x-axis starts at -1 but the new xticks
                   # should start at 0, the first entry is set to an
                   # empty string.
    for j,x in enumerate(y):
        newxticks.append(round(x,3))
    for j,h in enumerate(barchart):
        h.set_height(y[j])
        ax.set_xticklabels(newxticks)


anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,repeat=False,frames=n,interval=50)
plt.show()
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind that there is a difference between ticks and ticklabels. When setting a known number of ticklabels to an unknown number of ticks, the result can be anything.

In order to make sure each bar has its own ticklabel we can set the ticks to the positions of the bars.

```
ax.set_xticks(range(l))
```

We can then set the ticklabels to anything we want, but of course we would need as many ticklabels as we have ticks.

```
ax.set_xticklabels(newxticklabels)
```

A complete working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

n=100 #number of frames
l=13  #number of bars

def test_func(k): #just some test function, has no further meaning
    A=[]
    for i in range (l):
        numerator=(i+1)*k
        denominator=(i+k+1)**2+1
        A.append(numerator/float(denominator))
    return A

barlist=[] # the list of bars that is reused in each frame
for i in range(l):
    barlist.append(0)

fig=plt.figure()
ax=plt.axes(xlim=(-1,l),ylim=(0,0.5))  
barchart=ax.bar(range(l),barlist,align='center')
ax.set_xticks(range(l))

def animate(i):
    y=test_func(i)
    newxticklabels=[]
    for j,x in enumerate(y):
        newxticklabels.append(round(x,3))
    ax.set_xticklabels(newxticklabels)
    for j,h in enumerate(barchart):
        h.set_height(y[j])

anim=animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate,repeat=False,frames=n,interval=50)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you ImportanceOfBeingErnest! It's the second time now that you've answered my question and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. If you like the answer, consider upvoting it. This is true for any answer or question that you find here on SO: If you find an answer that you find well written or that helped you accomplish some task, upvote it.